# How do you translate “复盘”？

Tags: terminology, games

In the board game of 围棋 (Go), many players tend to analyse skills and techniques used in a game right after they have completed it. This review is known as 复盘 in Chinese.

Is there a specific term in English which refers to the act of reviewing past games for skill acquisition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say the best translation here would be `replay`, as this is what actually happens: The game is being replayed in order to improve the own skill and analyse the tactics/strategy.
Moreover, this is what Pleco offered as translation in the only available example sentence to this term:

> 他通过复盘给我讲解下棋策略。
>
> Tā tōngguò fù pán gěi wǒ jiǎngjiě xià qí cèlüè.
>
> He explains the tactics of chess to me by replaying the original situations of the chessboard.

Comment: @user3306356, will do as soon as I am at home!

Comment: @user3306356 done.

Answer (score 3):

复盘：

> To rearrange pieces according to the previous sequence when a board game is over in order to study the merits and faults of the game.

As metters said, replay seems good, or review or as it says: study the merits and faults of the game

Comment: "Review" is okay.  "Analyze" is what I'd normally say as a chess player (E.g. "Would you like to analyze the game?").  I feel "replay" is incorrect---a replay does not imply people are analyzing it; they could just be watching it.